# How do I set the Domain-level access policy in OpenSearch for only the VPC that it is in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

Current configuration:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-2:000000000000:domain/opensearch-dev/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

My goal is to ensure only systems within our dev VPC can access this opensearch cluster. Would this accomplish this or is this too permissive?

Comment: Am assuming you have set the network to be public ? Have you read this [AWS VPC Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/vpc.html)? And that the subnet / security group is defined also and associated with the domain ? Your question needs more information.

Comment: You can use condition. Something like `"Condition": { "StringEquals": {"aws:SourceVpc": "$yourvpc"}`

Comment: @t0mm13b 

I have already associated the desired vpc and subnets and security groups that restrict access. This is a private VPC.

Comment: One concern I had was that people or machines associated with the IAM role would have unrestricted access to OpenSearch via the AWS CLI for example.

Comment: Two options, a reverse proxy such as nginx, on an instance that has just the IAM role to the opensearch domain endpoint and that has ldap access by a windows security group, that ties it down to just that machine, the other option is to enable cognito / granular access on the cluster where certain IAM roles can be associated with certain API endpoints, have not tried the latter as found it too cumbersome to implement.